# Read from a specific location in c#

Tags: c#, console

Hi i want to know if i can put the console.readline in a specific location.

I try this:

```
Console.Writeline("Type a number: ");
Console.SetCursorPosition(x,y)
int opcion = int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But before that code, i have a foreach that reads the objects in a list

```
foreach (var producto in productos)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\n\tID: {producto.id_producto} || Categoria: {producto.Categoria} || 
                              Producto: {producto.Producto} || Precio: {producto.Precio}");
}
```

So i can't use 'SetCursosPosition(x,y)' because if i add objects to my list the '(x,y)' must be diferrent.

I want to know if its possible to put the set Console.ReadLine in a specific position.

Code:

```
foreach (var producto in productos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\n\tID: {producto.id_producto} || Categoria: {producto.Categoria} || Producto: {producto.Producto} || Precio: {producto.Precio}");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nIngrese el ID del Producto que desea comprar: ");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(46, 10);
            int Numero_producto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

[Image where the SetCursor is correct whit 4 objects in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FMGd.png)

[Image where the SetCursor is wrong because i add a object to the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WA4A.png)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use setcursorposition?  perhaps you don't know there is a GetCursorPosition so you can call that, find out where you are, then do the math to set the position to where you want?

Comment: You have to keep track during the list and update x and y accordingly.

Comment: When i put more objects in my list, and then use the foreach, more text is added to the console, and the strings change, I have to change the (x,y) of the setcursor point because it is different, since I added objects to the list and printed it on the console

Comment: You should show a screen shot of your output, along with where you want the cursor to go.  Then show how the output would change, and where you now want the cursor to go...   As it is, all we know is that you want to put the cursor "somewhere" and it's not working.

Comment: This is nothing to do with your question, but you should never really use `int.Parse` with user-entered text. Users make mistakes, and you don't want exceptions thrown because of simple typos. Use `int.TryParse` instead

Comment: i upload images to see if u can understand my question, sorry if im not clear.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, just keep track of the cursor position as you write your data. Don't forget to account for the new line characters (\n) in your strings.

See comments in code...

```
// create test data
IList<Product> products = new List<Product>()
{
    new Product(){ ProductId = 1, Category = "Cat 1", Price = 1.99m, ProductName = "Item 001"},
    new Product(){ ProductId = 2, Category = "Cat 1", Price = 2.99m, ProductName = "Item 002"},
    new Product(){ ProductId = 3, Category = "Cat 2", Price = 3.99m, ProductName = "Item 003"},
    new Product(){ ProductId = 4, Category = "Cat 2", Price = 4.99m, ProductName = "Item 004"},
};

// initialize row/column positions at start
int origColumn = Console.CursorLeft;
int origRow = Console.CursorTop;
int currentColumn = origColumn;
int currentRow = origRow;

// write items to console and keep track of currentRow
foreach (var p in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"\n\tProductId: {p.ProductId} || Category: {p.Category} || ProductName: {p.ProductName} || Price: {p.Price}");
    // add 2; one for each line written and one for each new line character (\n)
    currentRow = currentRow + 2;
}

// request input from user and loop request until int type is received
// or user enters 'q' or 'Q' to quit
int selectedProductId = 0;
string inputValue = string.Empty;
do
{
    string text = "Type a number ('Q' exit) > ";
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    currentColumn = text.Length; // set column from text length
    Console.SetCursorPosition(currentColumn, currentRow);
    inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
    int.TryParse(inputValue, out selectedProductId);
    currentRow++;
} while (selectedProductId == 0 && !inputValue.Equals("q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

// write selected product detail to console
Product selectedProduct = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductId == selectedProductId);
if (selectedProduct != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nSelected Product Detail:");
    Console.WriteLine($"ProductId: {selectedProduct.ProductId} || Category: {selectedProduct.Category} || ProductName: {selectedProduct.ProductName} || Price: {selectedProduct.Price}");
}
else if(!inputValue.Equals("q", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to locate that product Id.");
}
Console.WriteLine("\nDone.");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can see in the "wrong" image that the cursor is above the prompt by a couple lines.  My first question would be, why are you trying to explicitly set the position of that prompt?

Just output the prompt and leave the cursor where it is.

Change:

```
Console.WriteLine("\n\nIngrese el ID del Producto que desea comprar: ");
Console.SetCursorPosition(46, 10);
int Numero_producto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

To:

```
Console.Write("\n\nIngrese el ID del Producto que desea comprar: ");
int Numero_producto = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Note that `WriteLine()` has been changed to `Write()`, and we are NOT calling `SetCursorPosition()` at all, thus leaving the cursor immediately after the prompt where you would expect the input to occur.